# Extracting specifc items from enumerate to a new tex file

Tags: enumerate, itemize, extract

I have created a book using LaTeX in the below given format

```
\documentclass[ 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is item number 1 
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item option A 
        \item option B
        \item option C
        \item option D
    \end{itemize}
    
    \item This is item number 2
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle(1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \item This is item number 3 
    
    \item This is item number 4
    
    \item This is item number 5
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item option A
        \item option B
        \item option C
    \end{itemize}   

 \item This is item number 6
    
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I want to extract some specific items from `\enumerate`  environment to a new `.tex` file. Let's say items 1, 3 and 5. I searched a lot and found `extract` package as very useful for such tasks. But I couldn't extract above mentioned items as according to my need. I tried options according to the manual as given below in preamble:

```
\usepackage[active, generate=file, extract-env=enumerate, extract-cmdline={item}, extract-labels={ch}]{extract}
```

and `\extractionlabel{ch}` before the items I needed to extract. But the output file contains all items in the enumerate environment.

My desired output is as given below:

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is item number 1
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item option A 
        \item option B
        \item option C
        \item option D
    \end{itemize}
    
    \item This is item number 3 
    
    \item This is item number 5
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item option A
        \item option B
        \item option C
    \end{itemize}   
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your example, if you extracted item 1, would you want it to include the itemize environment as well, or just the `\item` line? (Nevermind, you do; not sure why I didn't read that properly...)

Comment: @frabjous as a clarification: I need the itemize environment too. It would be good if I get whatever environment comes under that item. It may be figure, tikzpicture, itemize etc.